# key=>Array[] syntax error in PHP

Tags: php, arrays

I want a key to point to an array inside an array, but I get an error in my PHP code, "unexpected '[' character. Do you guys know the right syntax?

```
public function insertBHDataTableName($BHDatabase) {
    $resultArray = array();
    $query = $this->m_queryFactory->getableNameInfo($BHDatabase);
    $result = odbc_exec($this->m_connection, $query);
    $no_results = odbc_num_rows($result);
    for ($i = 1; $i <= $no_results; $i++) {
        odbc_fetch_row($result, $i);
        $ColumnName = odbc_result($result, "ColumnName");
        $ColumnFullName = odbc_result($result, "ColumnFullName");
        $Unit = odbc_result($result, "Unit");
        $Formula = odbc_result($result, "Formula");
        $Format = odbc_result($result, "Format");
        array_push($resultArray,array($ColumnName=>[$ColumnFullName,$Unit,$Formula,$Format])); //Here is where I get my error   
    }
    return resultArray;
}
```

Comment: Upgrade to PHP 5.4 would be my advice.

Comment: your `PHP` version might not support array shorthand expression.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using [] to denote arrays is only valid in PHP5.4+

Change your line to

```
array($ColumnName=>array($ColumnFullName,$Unit,$Formula,$Format)))
```

and it will work.

Answer (score 0):

try with `array()` rather `[]`

```
array_push($resultArray,array($ColumnName=>array($ColumnFullName,$Unit,$Formula,$Format)));
```

or upgrade your php version to >=5.4 to active array shorthand